# Javascript data structure for json data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, jenkins

Hi I have some JSON data from Jenkins. I fetch the JSON and get jobs objects that look like this:

```
{
     color: "#FF4136"
     name: "XXX-tomcat-accept"
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"
}
```

For each job stream there are three jobs

- -verify
- -accept
- -delivery

What I am trying to do is to build a data structure that is an Array of Arrays OR a Hash of Arrays, in which the first element is verify then accept and then delivery(Same order as the above list).

So something like this

```
0[xxx-tomcat-verify,xxx-tomcat-accept,xxx-tomcat-delivery]
1[xxx-linux-verify,xxx-linux-accept,xxx-linux-delivery]
2
3
......
```

I just cannot wrap my head around the logic to reassemble the data in the above structure. What I am trying to do is to build a light weight build dashboard for Jenkins using d3. The below code builds the jobs and labels them. Just need to get them in the correct order.

the code i have thus is

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {

    job.forEach(function(d){

        //green balls !
        if (d.color === "blue") {
            d.color = "#2ECC40";
        }   else if(d.color === "notbuilt"){
            d.color = "#AAAAAA";

        } else if(d.color === "aborted"){
            d.color = "#0074D9";
        } else if(d.color === "red"){
            d.color = "#FF4136"

        }


        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                            .attr("width", 460)
                            .attr("height", 110);

        var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                            .attr("x", 5)
                            .attr("y", 5)
                            .attr("width", 450)
                            .attr("height", 100)
                            .attr("text", d.name)
                            .attr("rx", 10)
                            .attr("ry", 10)
                            .attr("xlink:href", d.url)
                            .attr("fill", d.color);

        var text = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
                        .data(rectangle)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text");

        var textLabels = text
                 .attr("x", 20)
                 .attr("y", 60)
                 .text(d.name)
                 .attr("font-family", "Avro")
                 .attr("font-size", "30px")
                 .attr("fill", "#2f2f2f");



        });

});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question, could you refine?

Comment: so i get my data back in an array of objects and I am trying to sort that into an array or arrays based on the name, with with the three member of the array in the order i outlined above.

Comment: Can you give a larger sample data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use d3.nest().

https://jsfiddle.net/ermineia/jz293y70/1/

```
var jobs = [{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-tomcat-verify",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"
},
{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-tomcat-accept",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"
},
{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-tomcat-delivery",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"
},
{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-linux-verify",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"
},
{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-linux-accept",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"
},
{
     color: "#FF4136",
     name: "XXX-linux-delivery",
     url: "http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"
}];

console.log( jobs );
var formatted_map = d3.nest().key( function( d ) { return d.name.substr( 0, d.name.lastIndexOf( '-' ) ); } ).map( jobs );
console.log( formatted_map );
console.log( JSON.stringify( formatted_map ))
var formatted_array = d3.nest().key( function( d ) { return d.name.substr( 0, d.name.lastIndexOf( '-' ) ); } ).entries( jobs );
console.log( formatted_array );
console.log( JSON.stringify( formatted_array ))
```

Writes out:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
(index):78 Object {XXX-tomcat: Array[3], XXX-linux: Array[3]}
(index):79 {"XXX-tomcat":[{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-verify","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-accept","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-delivery","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"}],"XXX-linux":[{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-verify","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-accept","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-delivery","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"}]}
(index):81 [Object, Object]
(index):82 [{"key":"XXX-tomcat","values":[{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-verify","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-accept","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-tomcat-delivery","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"}]},{"key":"XXX-linux","values":[{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-verify","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-verify/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-accept","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-accept/"},{"color":"#FF4136","name":"XXX-linux-delivery","url":"http://1.1.7.9:8080/job/xxx-tomcat-delivery/"}]}]
```